# Undo javascript calculation with | 0 to round the number

Tags: javascript, class, rounding, undo

I have following table and JavaScript that calculates my temperature to farenheid.

I want to toggle between celcius and Fahrenheit but obviesly if 
i reverse the calculation after I round the number the temperature is different.

I would like the original number back. I have About 200 different numbers all with the same class. I hope somone could help me. Thank you.

```js
function change_to_gf()
  {

  var myClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("a_e");
  for (var i = 0; i < myClasses.length; i++)
    {
    myClasses[i].innerHTML = (((myClasses[i].innerHTML -32 ) / 1.8) | 0)
    }
 
  var myClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("a_mr");
  for (var i = 0; i < myClasses.length; i++)
    {
    myClasses[i].innerHTML = (((myClasses[i].innerHTML -32 ) / 1.8 | 0))
    }
  }
```

```html
<table style="width:920px;" align="center" id="sort1" data-name="mytable" class="4sort1">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:60px;" class="a_e" id="exo_bist_e"/>48
    <td style="width:60px;" class="a_mr" id="exo_bist_mr"/>52
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Both `32F` and `33F` will "convert" to `0C`. What do you expect `0C` to convert to?

Comment: Save the original value somewhere.

Comment: Put the unrounded value in a `data-XXX` attribute of the element. Use that when undoing it.

Comment: Also, use `Math.round()` rather than `| 0` to convert to integer.

Comment: If you can only use integers then this is not possible, as Fahrenheit has a higher precision when only using integers than Celsius. For every 9 distinct Fahrenheit degrees, you only have 5 Celsius degrees. So you cannot reach all 9 F° with only 5 available C°

Comment: sorry, the calculations was wrong. it schould be    myClasses[i].innerHTML = (((myClasses[i].innerHTML * 1.8) +32) | 0)

Comment: @ Barmar. Your answer seams the Right one for me, but how do I store my Array globally so that the unrounded value is accessible from every function.    var myClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("a_e"); schould be global

Comment: `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("a_e"); y_e = [];
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
 {
 y_e.push(x[i].innerHTML);
 }
 for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
 {
 x[i].innerHTML = (((y_e[i] * 1.8 ) + 32) | 0)
 }`      Thanks barmar I figured it out.